# restore php projects when re-install wampserver

Tags: php, wampserver, data-recovery

I forced to reinstall wamp on my pc. but i forgot to copy all php project on www folder on wamp and when install wamp again realize that all my php files are lose.
Can someone tell me how to restore it. I do in big trouble

Thank you.

Comment: Usually those are regular files and the only way to restore is either if those files were saved no a backup or or from the trash

Comment: Don't you back your files up? If they're even slightly important you should be backing them up regularly, either syncing to cloud storage or at least saving to an external disk. This is computer-usage basics...a programmer should know better.

Answer (score 0):

You replaced some data in a directory, even if you, recover your data, they are maybe damaged.

But

`Comfy File Recovery`

is the application you can recover deleted folder, you should search for a recovery applications

NOTE:

I highly recommend don't waste your time to recover the codes that even you didn't get back up or push them in `github` or `gitlab` you will face a lot of troubles about your codes and databases...